# Potluck (Food) Menu Sign up form

Tags: forms, navigation

I am looking a way to create a food menu sign up sheet. 
Login user can select food menu from the list, If somebody picks the food, it is disabled, so nobody can sign up for that item again. Is there anything like this out there?

Answer (score 1):

You could try a wishlist or gift registry module. Here's one. I haven't tried this but it should disable or remove items from the list once people select them.

https://www.drupal.org/project/wishlist

Please note that this question has multiple or too many possible answers, so it might get disabled.